# How to get live heart rate from Garmin vivoactive 3 in iOS app?

Tags: ios, garmin, connectiq

Is it possible to collect live heart rate data from Garmin vivoactive 3 watch to iOS app by using ConnectIQ.Framework or any other way to do this.